# Justify bottom and top div contents, and keep content in the middle centered

Tags: html, css

Before anything, I'm very new to this **HTML** and **CSS** world.

I have this **HTML** code:

```
<section class="instructions">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="instructions-col">
            <h5>1.</h5>
            <p>First, you'll need to choose your language. Click the button indicated.</p>
            <img src="media/instructions/1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="instructions-col">
            <h5>2.</h5>
            <p>Use the switch to choose your language.</p>
            <img src="media/instructions/2.png">
        </div>
        <div class="instructions-col">
            <h5>3.</h5>
            <p>When the right language is selected, click the indicated button.</p>
            <img src="media/instructions/3.png">
        </div>
        <div class="instructions-col">
            <h5>4.</h5>
            <p>Elderoid's idiom is now updated. Click the indicated button to continue.</p>
            <img src="media/instructions/4.png">
        </div>
        <div class="instructions-col">
            <h5>5.</h5>
            <p>This is the welcome screen. Click the indicated button to continue.</p>
            <img src="media/instructions/5.png">
        </div>
    </div> 
</section>
```

This code creates a row of divs, each containing a **title**, a **paragraph** and an **image**.

I also added this **CSS** code:

```
.instructions {
   width: 80%;
   margin: auto;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.instructions-col {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    flex-basis: 15%;
    background: #fff7f3;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.instructions-col p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.instructions-col img {
    padding-top: 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Resulting in this:

[image]

I all looks pretty close to what I'm aiming for, except for column **2** (the second div). As you can see in the picture, the **paragraph** is smaller and that results in the **images** not getting lined up horizontally.

I need the **images** to be aligned to the bottom of the div (all at the same level), so as the **titles** to be aligned to the top of the div (all at the same level too). Also, the **paragraph** in the middle, should be centered between the **title** and **image**.

I've been playing with *margins* and the *justify-content* tag, but haven't been able to pull it off.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` to `.instructions-col`. Also add `flex: 1` to paragraph. Then your paragraph will push heading to top and image to bottom. If you add `display: flex` and `align-items: center` to paragraph, it will be centered between heading and image.

Please take a look at an example of this.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column p {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <h5>Title</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/100x100">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h5>Title</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt omnis molestiae dolorum nam eius incidunt?</p>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/100x100">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h5>Title</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/100x100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That makes so much sense. Thank you for enlightening me! Works like a charm.

Comment: I am glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

The cause is the text, not the images. You have an image under a paragraph of text, so the position of the image depends on where the text ends. The other blocks of text have 3 lines, but in col 2 it's just two lines. So, the image starts a line higher.

The solution is either to add more text (even a line break) to make all the text blocks the same size, or to align the image to the bottom of the containing div (using flexbox, ideally) rather than being positioned based on the text block as is the case now.

Comment: Answer is to broad for SO. Please add a [repro] to validate your answer and show how it works.

Comment: I've provided exactly the detail required for the simple solution (change the text flow). For this question, flexbox is overkill and so I chose not to go into that level of detail, especially for a beginner. The accepted answer doesn't actually explain the initial problem and just gives details about using flexbox.